# regex: replace dynamically a searched word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace `file:///Downloads/project` by a another word like a github link :

```
const string = 'file:///Downloads/project/users/controllers/users/controller.js';
```

I tried working with .replace a world by a world but i got in the problem that `file:///Downloads/project`is a dynamic value that may change from time to time.

```
string.replace(/file\:\/\/Downloads\/project\/users\/controller.js/gi, 'https://gitlab.com')
```

So i want to search for the word `project` and replace from it backward by another path or word

Comment: why do you need regex?

Comment: i'm reading about some way of replacing a substring by regex so i think that's the only ways instead of writing a whole function

Comment: `string.replace('file:///Downloads/project', 'mynewvalue')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using indexOf and substr and finally replacing with gitlab url

1. Get index of project
2. Get string from 0 to index of project
3. Replace string from step 2 with gitlab using replace option

```js
const string = 'file:///Downloads/project/users/controllers/users/controller.js';
const index = string.indexOf('project') 
console.log(string.replace(string.substr(0, index), 'https://gitlab.com/'))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qvjdEa?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can match the first group which includes `/project` and replace the first parenthesized capture group with your `https://gitlab.com`. Here `p1` denotes first parenthesized capture group and `p2` denotes second parenthesized capture group.

```js
const str = 'file:///Downloads/project/users/controllers/users/controller.js';

const res = str.replace(/^(.|\/)+\w*project(.+)*/gi, function(match, p1, p2) {
  return 'https://gitlab.com' + p2;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a regex for that

```js
const string = 'file:///Downloads/project/users/controllers/users/controller.js',
  yourValue = "file:///Downloads/project/",
  res = string.replace(yourValue, "https://gitlab.com/")

console.log(res)
```

Comment: i retreive string dynamically so the value file:///Downloads/project changes

Answer (score 0):

```
'https://gitlab.com/' + string.substr(string.indexOf('project'))
```

---

First find the position of 'project' in your string

```
string.indexOf('project')
```

then get a substring from that position to the end of the string (substr goes till the end when no second arg is provided)

```
string.substring(indexOfProject)
```

then concat it with '+'. Note that the url ends with '/' because your string will begin with 'p'.

```
'https://gitlab.com/' + extractedString
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.